# CSS issue on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipad, mobile-safari

I have a very simple `CSS` related question on iPad.
I have a set of sublinks each defined in CSS as;

```
#leftNav .searchBySub {...}
#leftNav a.searchBySub:hover {...}
#leftNav .searchBySubClicked {...}
```

And I have a `JS` where I have defined

```
$("#leftNav  a.searchBySub").live("touchstart",function(){...}
$("#leftNav  a.searchBySub").live("click",function(){...}
```

Now my question is when I click on any of the sublinks on the iPad, why does it apply the :hover state CSS to it ? Also can I change that behavior somehow ?

Please read the question carefully before making any simple/basic suggestions, as I have already tried the basic fixes..

Also before you say, there is no hover event on the iPad, I am aware of that, but in my case, it does apply the :hover state class when the link is clicked..

I know you might say just remove the :hover definition from the CSS, but unfortunately I cannot do that, as the same CSS is used by the desktop browsers as well (and even with media queries, it does not help)

So my main question is how do I override the :hover state when the link is clicked ?

Updated ...

Below is the code I have tried;

```
    $("#leftNav  a.searchBySub").live("touchstart",function(){
                var a=document.getElementsByClassName("searchBySub");                 
                for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)                 
                {                         
                a[i].ontouchstart=function(e){
 window.location=this.getAttribute("href");
                console.log("ontouchstart2");
                e.stopPropagation();                                 
                e.preventDefault(); 
                return false;}                 
                }
                $("#leftNav  a.searchBySub").removeClass("searchBySubClick");
                $(this).addClass("searchBySubClick");
                clickEvent($(this));
            });
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the hover state? Since you are saying that the hover state isn't present on the iPad, how can it be applied? Maybe for the sake of compatibility, mobile safari may treat the :hover as it would be a :active, or :focus one instead.

Try to specify rules for the :active or :focus links, to see if that changes something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Safari mobiles handles the event on a particular order: when you press then release screen here is what happens:

```
ontouchstart - onmouseover/:hover - mousedown - mouseup - click/:active
```

Notice that `onmouseout` (end of the `:hover` state) won't be called unless you click elsewhere. Took me a while to figure that out.

As a workaround you can use this kind of code to trigger your links *before* the onmouseover event occurs.

```
        function ipadLinksHack()//Call it onload
        {
                var a=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
                for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
                {
                        //Note to self: ontouchstart and not onclick! :)
                        a[i].ontouchstart=function(e)
                        {
                                window.location=this.getAttribute("href");
                                e.stopPropagation();
                                e.preventDefault();
                                return false;//Prevents the link default behavior
                        }
                }
        }
```

**Remark**: you can also use this snippet to prevent the opening of safari when you're in "standalone mode" (aka webapp) and click on links. That was the main purpose of this function.
Also, reading the [event handling guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) on the official doc might help.

Comment: Thx a lot...You seem to have understood the question really well....While I tried the code you gave in my app, it still is applying the :hover CSS on the iPad...So still looking for some way to override it..

Comment: Sorry I've made a mistake, in the above code, I add my hack on the `onclick()` event, wich happens AFTER the `:hover`. Should have put it to `ontouchstart` event. My bad. (I edited the code above feel free to try again).

Comment: ok...no issues..I'll try the same...So essentially the code above would cancel/prevent the link to go into hover state when it is clicked on the iPad...Is that correct?

Comment: It fires the redirections before the `:hover` state, and try to prevent the other events to trigger with the `return false;`. So basically, yes.

Comment: Ok..Thx a lot for the details...It'll take me some time to test this thing on an iPad..but surely by tomorrow...I'll post my findings over here as soon as that is done...Please do keep this on your radar for the same..Thx again for all the wonderful tips/solutions which u have provided...

Comment: Just to add, this question is actually part of an issue i m facing on iPad..i.e. Theree are 5 sublinks and on click/touch of any of them, even though i do removeClass for all and then add class using "this" to the clicked sublink only, the previously selected link still shows some selected color, bcoz of hover...So the solution u gave would actually be applied by me as part of this entire flow...

Comment: Hi again, I did try the a[i].ontouchstart= code....But unfortunately the hover styles still get applied on the iPad....Not really sure what the issue might be...

Comment: Can you check if the ontouchstart function is triggered? `console.log();` or `window.alert();` to check out. Then try to add `e.preventDefault. Code updated once more.

Comment: Thx again for replying...I tested with the updated code...It indeed goes inside ontouchstart function...i can see a console message being outputted from there...Still the hover styles are getting applied even after e.stopPropagation(); and e.preventDefault();

Comment: I was also thinking of an alternate way to fix this..i.e. through trigger a mouseout event on the link through JS...However even that is not working for some reasons...I tried $("#leftNav  a").mouseout(); ....$("#leftNav  a").trigger("mouseout"); 
$("#leftNav  a").trigger("mouseleave");

Comment: could u get a chance to go through the issue ?

Comment: I don't have the problem as my links actually redirects to another page. The redirection happens before the styling, so it isn't seen.

Answer (score 0):

> When the user focuses on an element by single-tapping it, the :hover styles are applied and the mouseover, mousemove, mousedown, mouseup and click events fire (always; and in that order).

So :hover is applied even on iOS. Not sure if iOS supports :focus (or maybe :active), but you could use that one to 'undo' the changes made by :hover.

Or use JS to call .blur() (untested).

Comment: Exactly....That is the issue I am facing ...the :hover CSS getting applied on the iPad...Not sure if there is a standard fix for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look about the `document.styleSheets[0].deleteRule()` function, and simply delete every rule containing ":hover" relative to a links. 
Here is [some doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM%3astylesheet.deleteRule) and [some example of usage](http://help.dottoro.com/ljcihbgl.php).

Be careful as pseudo element scripting seems unreliable on most browsers, so just loop through the stylesheet and delete "a:hover" rules.